# Adding three pickers cause touch problems

Tags: swift, swiftui, picker

We divided form by 3 and to each part we added wheel picker. The problem is touch of the pickers is moved so we can't easly change values. Form is in side bar.

Below three pickers in form.

```
Form {
                    
                    Section {
                        TextField("\(nodes.n_array[id].text)", text: $nodes.n_array[id].text)
                        } header: { Text("Tekst") }
                    
                    Section {
                        HStack(spacing: 0) {
                                
                                Picker("Red", selection: $nodes.n_array[id].red) {
                                    
                                    ForEach(0...255, id: \.self) { red in
                                        Text("\(red)")
                                    }
                                    
                                }
                                .pickerStyle(.wheel)
                                .frame(minWidth: 0)
                                .clipped()
                                
                                
                                Picker("Green", selection: $nodes.n_array[id].green) {
                                    
                                    ForEach(0...255, id: \.self) { green in
                                        Text("\(green)")
                                    }
                                    
                                }
                                .pickerStyle(.wheel)
                                .frame(minWidth: 0)
                                .clipped()
                                
                                Picker("Blue", selection: $nodes.n_array[id].blue) {
                                    
                                    ForEach(0...255, id: \.self) { blue in
                                        Text("\(blue)")
                                    }
                                    
                                }
                                .pickerStyle(.wheel)
                                .frame(minWidth: 0)
                                .clipped()
                                
                                
                            }
                    } header: { Text("Kolor") }
                            
                }
            
                }
```

[Working application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kzFV.jpg)

Comment: Please post code, not pictures of code, which can't be copied/pasted, searched, or read by screen readers

Comment: there is not even any code about pickers in the bit of pasted picture.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.